# Train a model Sentiment Analysis scikit learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, sentiment-analysis

I am getting started with NLP and Sentiment Analysis.

I would like to train a model with Scikit-Learn for detecting the sentiment of tweets.
I have a labeled dataset of tweets, how should I train a model (can I have some sample code with a Bayes classifier?)

```
df = pd.read_csv('Trainded Dataset - Sentiment.csv', error_bad_lines=False)
df.head(5)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to extract bag-of-words features from the text, you'll need to run `CountVectorizer` or `TfidfVectorizer` on text column.

The rest is pretty straightforward, scikit-learn has an example code [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/grid_search_text_feature_extraction.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-model-selection-grid-search-text-feature-extraction-py).
For Naive Bayes you'd need to change `SGDClassifier` to appropriate [Naive Bayes algorithm from scikit](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/naive_bayes.html) and maybe drop `TfidfTransformer` (it does tf-idf scaling of the counts, so it doesn't help if you only use bare counts, as in Multinomial/Bernoulli Naive Bayes).

Answer (score 1):

## from sklearn you should import train_test_split

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

## columns used for training

x=df['SentimentText']

y=df['Sentiment']

## split in test and train

x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(x,y, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)

## encoding the labels (0&1)

encoder = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()

y_train = encoder.fit_transform(y_train)

y_test = encoder.fit_transform)

## vectorizing with TF=IDF

tfidf_vect = TfidfVectorizer(analyzer='word', token_pattern=r'\w{1,}', max_features=5000)

tfidf_vect.fit(df['SentimntText'])

xtrain_tfidf =  tfidf_vect.transform(x_train)

xvalid_tfidf =  tfidf_vect.transform(x_test)

## trian with MNB

naive_bayes = MultinomialNB()

predictions = naive_bayes.fit(xtrain_tfidf , xvalid_tfidf , y_train)

accuracy = metrics.accuracy.score(predictions, y_test)

Comment: Can you properly format your answer? See [this manual](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for instructions.